# How to convert a WordPress theme to AMP Ready theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, amp-html

I want to make Robot - Multipurpose WordPress Theme to AMP(accelerated-mobile-pages) ready using child theme without using any AMP plugins, can any one help me?

Answer (score -1):

Without using any plugins, it would be pretty darn tricky, because your theme would have to take responsibility for converting ("sanitizing") all of the user's content into something AMP-valid. For example, your theme would have to filter the post content to replace all `<img>` tags with `<amp-img>`. And that's really only the beginning. To get a sense of how much work it is to do it right, take a look at the [Changelog for the Amp for WordPress plugin](https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp#changelog).

Basically, there's a reason the plugins exist.

Version 0.7 of the AMP for WordPress plugin (which is not released yet as of this writing) allows your theme to provide custom templates for the AMP pages it serves. That sounds like what you want. (For my part, I know it's what I want. I'm currently adding AMP support to my theme using version 0.7beta1 of the plugin.)

Answer (score -1):

Start with making a child theme using a basic theme with amp features already integrated.
This is a good example free. 
https://allthingsblogging.com/downloads/startablog-pro-amp-html-theme/

Allows you to become familiar with Amp quick and once you feel comfortable and want to create your own theme you can use the same integrations offered in the free template without the unnecessary elements.

Answer (score -3):

May I ask why you are not keen to use plugin for this purpose?

In case you change your mind there is a plugin for AMP-ing your WordPress site called **AMP for WordPress** ( probably you knew it already )

https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/

It is also supported by Automaticc.

You can try it. It does pretty good job.

Comment: Yes I knew and already using it. But i want to create a theme AMP ready. Do you have any idea how to convert any theme to be AMP ready?

Comment: The only way that would work is to distribute the theme with the plugin which will be stored in the `mu-plugins` folder. After that you can just call `add_theme_support( 'amp' )` in your theme's functions.php file. Not sure if this will work 100% but you can try it!